# Does WMI query allow group by?

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

I have a WMI query on Win32_Processor.
When I test the query on a server that has 2 processors with 4 cores each it returns the same information for each core.
Does WMI query allows group by, lets say, Win32_Processor.Caption when I send the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the WMI querys uses the [`WQL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) language which is a subset of the ANSI SQL and doesn't supports the `group by` clause.

Note : don't confuse with the WQL [`GROUP Clause`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390846%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is valid only for event querys.